# attribute for on label not working on knockout component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, components

here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32887/

I have a knockout component that is a bootstrap form input.  however it appears on the label the for = foo is not working (clicking on the label does not highlight the input)

component.

```
   ko.components.register('form-input', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.inputValue = params.value;
        this.label = params.label
        this.placeHolder = params.placeHolder
        this.id = params.id
        this.formControl = ko.pureComputed(function() {
             return !this.inputValue() ? "form-group has-error" : "form-group";
        }, this);
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="css: formControl">\
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2" \
             data-bind ="attr: {for: id}"> \
             <span data-bind="text: label"></span>:</label>\
               <div class="col-sm-9">\
               <input type="text"\
                 class="form-control"\
                 data-bind="textInput: inputValue, \
                 attr: {placeholder: placeHolder, id: id}">\
                 </div>\
            </div>'
});
```

javascript

```
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.firstName = ko.observable('Bryan');
  this.lastName = ko.observable('Dellinger');
  this.phone = ko.observable('800-GET-GIFT');
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

html

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <form-input
     params="value: firstName,
             label: 'First Name', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter First Name',
             id = 'FirstName' ">
   </form-input>
    <form-input
     params="value: lastName,
             label: 'Last Name', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter Last Name',
             id = 'LastName' ">
   </form-input>
    <form-input
     params="value: phone,
             label: 'Phone', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter Phone Number',
             id = 'phone' ">
   </form-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in your html. Try changing '=' in your params and use ':' instead:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <form-input
     params="value: firstName,
             label: 'First Name', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter First Name',
             id: 'FirstName' ">
   </form-input>
    <form-input
     params="value: lastName,
             label: 'Last Name', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter Last Name',
             id: 'LastName' ">
   </form-input>
    <form-input
     params="value: phone,
             label: 'Phone', 
             placeHolder: 'Enter Phone Number',
             id: 'phone' ">
   </form-input>
</div>
```